# Can I do in-camera double exposures on my Canon EOS 600?

Tags: canon, film-cameras, double-exposure

I am trying to do in-camera double exposures on my (film) Canon EOS 600. Is there is a way to turn off the automatic wind on or another way to make this possible?

Answer (score 4):

The Canon EOS 600 film camera is also known as the EOS 630 in North America. Yes, it can do up to 9 multiple exposures on one frame.

To shoot multiple exposures, press the “Mode” and “EXP.COMP” buttons simultaneously, and then select the number of exposures you want per frame with the control wheel near the shutter button.

[image]